# Why does this callback run indefinitely?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I've recently stumbled upon this very useful code which I got from this link https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp.

I've modified the code for clarity reasons and so "application" class is imported as an external class. I'm trying to understand why "set_temperature_callback" is called indefinitely in a loop. The interval of the loop is defined by NOTIFY_TIMEOUT. Here the interval is set to 1000 ms. I'm using this code as a peripheral for one of my Unity projects and it's working fine. I really appreciate any help!

```
import dbus

from advertisement import Advertisement
from service import Service, Characteristic, Descriptor
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature

#testing code
#------------------------------------------#
from application import Application
import inspect as i
import sys

def FindSource(method):
    sys.stdout.write(i.getsource(method))
#------------------------------------------#

GATT_CHRC_IFACE = "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"

#the interval between sending messages, is counted in milliseconds, was 5000
NOTIFY_TIMEOUT = 1000

class ThermometerAdvertisement(Advertisement):
    def __init__(self, index):
        Advertisement.__init__(self, index, "peripheral")
        self.add_local_name("Raspberry (thermometer)")
        self.include_tx_power = True

class ThermometerService(Service):
    #the service we're interested and is displayed in unity
    THERMOMETER_SVC_UUID = "00000001-710e-4a5b-8d75-3e5b444bc3cf"

    def __init__(self, index):
        self.farenheit = True

        Service.__init__(self, index, self.THERMOMETER_SVC_UUID, True)
        self.add_characteristic(TempCharacteristic(self))
        self.add_characteristic(UnitCharacteristic(self))

    def is_farenheit(self):
        return self.farenheit

    def set_farenheit(self, farenheit):
        self.farenheit = farenheit

class TempCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    TEMP_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00000002-710e-4a5b-8d75-3e5b444bc3cf"

    def __init__(self, service):
        self.notifying = False

        Characteristic.__init__(
                self, self.TEMP_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                ["notify", "read"], service)
        self.add_descriptor(TempDescriptor(self))

    def get_temperature(self):
        value = []
        unit = "C"

        # code here repeats
        cpu = CPUTemperature()
        temp = cpu.temperature
        
        if self.service.is_farenheit():
            temp = (temp * 1.8) + 32
            unit = "F"

        strtemp = str(round(temp, 1)) + " " + unit
        for c in strtemp:
            value.append(dbus.Byte(c.encode()))

        return value

    # the entire method will run on a loop  when unity app hits "subscribe"
    def set_temperature_callback(self):
        if self.notifying:
            print("running inside set_temperature_callback")
            value = self.get_temperature()
            
            self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, {"Value": value}, [])
        return self.notifying

    def StartNotify(self):
        print("Start notify first time")
        
        if self.notifying:
            print("returning from start notify")
            return

        self.notifying = True

        value = self.get_temperature()
        self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, {"Value": value}, [])
        self.add_timeout(NOTIFY_TIMEOUT, self.set_temperature_callback)

    def StopNotify(self):
        self.notifying = False

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        value = self.get_temperature()

        return value

class TempDescriptor(Descriptor):
    TEMP_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = "2901"
    TEMP_DESCRIPTOR_VALUE = "CPU Temperature test"

    def __init__(self, characteristic):
        Descriptor.__init__(
                self, self.TEMP_DESCRIPTOR_UUID,
                ["read"],
                characteristic)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        value = []
        desc = self.TEMP_DESCRIPTOR_VALUE

        for c in desc:
            value.append(dbus.Byte(c.encode()))

        return value

class UnitCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    UNIT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00000003-710e-4a5b-8d75-3e5b444bc3cf"

    def __init__(self, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(
                self, self.UNIT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                ["read", "write"], service)
        self.add_descriptor(UnitDescriptor(self))

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        val = str(value[0]).upper()
        if val == "C":
            self.service.set_farenheit(False)
        elif val == "F":
            self.service.set_farenheit(True)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        value = []

        if self.service.is_farenheit(): val = "F"
        else: val = "C"
        value.append(dbus.Byte(val.encode()))

        return value

class UnitDescriptor(Descriptor):
    UNIT_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = "2901"
    UNIT_DESCRIPTOR_VALUE = "Temperature Units (F or C)"

    def __init__(self, characteristic):
        Descriptor.__init__(
                self, self.UNIT_DESCRIPTOR_UUID,
                ["read"],
                characteristic)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        value = []
        desc = self.UNIT_DESCRIPTOR_VALUE

        for c in desc:
            value.append(dbus.Byte(c.encode()))

        return value

app = Application()
app.add_service(ThermometerService(0))
app.register()

adv = ThermometerAdvertisement(0)
adv.register()
```

Comment: The callback starts when the client connects to the peripherals and requests notifications of this characteristics. This is fairly typical for how you get information from a sensor with BLE. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking this from a programming point of view, why is this method running in a loop? Where is the loop and how can I control it so that it may send other data, even a randomly generated number, instead of the temperature?

Comment: It is running in the `mainloop` (which you don't appear to be starting in your version). It is the D-Bus `PropertiesChanged` that sends the data. `GObject.timeout_add` is how the timed event is added to `GObject.MainLoop()`

Comment: Thank you very very much, I'll make some tests to see if I can change the callback to a random generator function.